# Does open auditorium make sense?

Tags: vocabulary

The university organized an open auditorium on domestic violence. 
Does open auditorium make sense?
thanks

Comment: open forum, open hearing, open discussion...

Answer (score 2):

No, not quite.  An *open auditorium* is an auditorium open to the elements, and it's not something that a university would organise, though it might build one.  I don't find any support for the use of *auditorium* to mean *a meeting held in an auditorium*.

I suspect you want *The university organized an open meeting on domestic violence*.

Comment: I suggest *open auditorium* is actually jargon: it would make perfect sense in its context among its cognoscenti. Advertising such an event in that way to a wider audience is probably not the best course of action, though, I agree.

Comment: Well, perhaps, but then almost any phrase *might* be jargon.  Do you have any evidence of that usage, perhaps from a public notice of such an open auditorium/meeting ?